# Divergence Thm. and Continuity of Partial Derivatives, Vector Calculus

Tags: multivariable-calculus, continuity, proof-writing, divergence-theorem

This is the entire text of the problem.

> Determine whether the statement is true or false.  If it is true, explain why.  If it is false, explain why or give an example that shows it is false.

$$\text{If } div \mathbf{F} = 0 \text{  then }\iint _S \mathbf{F}\cdot d \mathbf{S}= 0 \text{ for every closed surface S.}$$

The textbook says the answer is $\mathbf{true}$.  This is a Calculus III, Multivariable Calculus text so it's possible to prove without sophisticated real analysis.
How do we know the partial derivatives are continuous?  Yes, the divergence is zero but I can create two functions whose sum is zero but have discontinuities.  Because it's not usually covered until Analysis, the text does not mention the following theorem.  "A function with a finite [or can they be countably finite?] number of discontinuities is integrable."  So of course a function exists whose derivative has any number of discontinuities.  Let this function be P_x, Q = -P and R =$0$.  Then $\mathbf{F} = Px + Qy + Rz$ has divergence = $0$. I can justify the partials being finite. I see two options.

A. Does Divergence theorem apply even when the partial derivatives are discontinuous?
B. Is there some way to prove from $div\mathbf{F}=0$, that the partial derivatives are continuous? 
This is from $\mathbf{\text{Calculus Early Transcendentals}}$ by Soo T. Tan, copyright 2011, section 14.8, page 1307, question number 27.

[image: Divergence Theorem]

Comment: In general, the divergence theorem does, indeed, require a continuous vector field. There are, apparently, clever ways to make the theorem consistent with discontinuous vector fields though...                                                          
                      https://solmaz.io/notes/discontinuous-divergence-theorem/

Comment: What if there are an infinite number of partitions required?